# Laying out screen. Need toolbar to stay on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to devide screen into 2 vertical segments. Bottom toolbar should be fixed - Let's say I want LinearLayout to stay at bottom no matter what.

On top - I want ScrollView that will grow up to toolbar and then allow to scroll. Otherwise - it can be completely empty but toolbar still need to be on a bottom.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always, there are several ways.  I would do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This uses a vertical linear layout and puts the buttons on the bottom using wrap_content, then gives the ScrollView the rest of the space by giving it a weight of "1".

Comment: If I could give this answer 1000 upvotes, I would. I've been fighting with getting this layout to work correctly for a while(still kinda new to android layouts). This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, the key is the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the second LinearLayout that here holds two buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Some text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/ok_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/cancel_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ok_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```